# collections pages loop not working on github

Tags: loops, github, collections, jekyll, github-pages

- Jekyll Version: 2.4.0
- github pages Version: 35

#### My Reproduction Steps

1. Build on locally and the looping of collections `site.collections.guides.docs` shown, generated the correct `.html` in `_site` folder as well.
2. However, when I deploy to github, it doesn't show the loop content.

#### The Output I Wanted

shown the loop in github pages, appreciate if someone have a look [on my repo](https://github.com/vincent-louis/pixelcss/tree/gh-pages).

#### my codes:

```
// index.html
{% for doc in site.collections.guides.docs %}
  {{ doc.content }}
{% endfor %}

// _config.yml
collections :
  guides:
    output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
{% for doc in site.guides %}
  {{ doc.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

And the config like this:

```
collections:
  guides:
    output: true
```